# Is there a way to rebuild the app navigating routes in a simple way ?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm currently working on a generic way to build a navigation panel to the users from all the routes of the application.

So far, I've found a working solution, but that involves adding data to my routes and a lot of code. I was wondering if there would be a more simple solution.

---

First and foremost, here are my (reduced) routes :

**master-routing.module.ts** :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MasterComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard, RoleGuard],
    data: {
      roles: ['user'],
      displayRoute: true,
      frenchName: 'General',
      englishName: 'General',
      materialIcon: 'view_headline'
    },
    resolve: {
      currentUser: CurrentUserResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: {
          displayRoute: true,
          frenchName: 'Dashboard',
          englishName: 'Dashboard',
          materialIcon: 'dashboard'
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'equipments',
        loadChildren: 'app/equipments/equipment.module#EquipmentModule',
        data: {
          displayRoute: true,
          frenchName: 'Equipements',
          englishName: 'Equipments',
          materialIcon: 'clear'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**equipment-routing.module.ts** :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'manage',
    component: ManageEquipmentsComponent,
    data: {
      displayRoute: true,
      moduleName: 'equipments',
      frenchName: 'Importer des équipements',
      englishName: 'Import equipments',
      materialIcon: 'settings_remote'
    }
  },
];
```

As you can see, I have a child route lazy-loading a module, and this module defines his own routes.

---

Here comes the headache :

My `MasterComponent` is linked to 2 components : `HeaderComponent` which allows me to search through my routes, a `NavBarComponent` which shows the main routes and the sub routes of my application. This is what I needed :

- A way to build my routes so that my sub-routes that come from a lazy-loaded module can be displayed as well
- An `Array` of built routes that I can send to my `HeaderComponent` so I can search my routes from their `frenchName` or `englishName`
- A `Tree` of routes similar to the `router.config` so I can display my base routes and their sub routes that I can send to my `NavBarComponent`.

Here is the code to get my `Array` of built routes :

**master.component.ts**

```
parentModules: ParentModule[] = [];
navigableRoutes: RouteDisplay[] = [];


constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private identityService: IdentityService,
  private authService: AuthService,
  private applicationsService: ApplicationsService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getRoutesToDisplay(this.router.config);
  console.log('navigableRoutes => ', this.navigableRoutes);
  this.navigationTree = this.buildNavigationTree(this.navigableRoutes);
  console.log('navigationTree => ', this.navigationTree);
}
```

**master.component.ts (1st part)**

```
  /**
  * Recursively builds the application navigation from the router config
  * @param {Route[]} routeNode Current node routes to browse
  * @param {string} parent Parent of the current routeNode
  *
  * @see Doesn't manage duplicate routes
  */
  getRoutesToDisplay(routeNode: Route[], parent?: string): void {
    let currentParent: string = (parent != null) ? parent : null;

    routeNode.forEach((route: RouteConfig) => {
      let pathFormatter: string = '';

      // Paths with Ids
      if (!route.path.includes(':')) {
        // Manage module routes
        if (route.loadChildren) {
          this.parentModules.push({ path: route.path, parent: currentParent });
        }

        // Checks if the route is to be displayed
        if (route.data && route.data.displayRoute && route.data.frenchName && route.data.englishName && route.data.materialIcon
          && ((route.data.roles && this.identityService.hasRole(route.data.roles)) || !route.data.roles)) {

          if (route.data.moduleName) {
            // Get the matching parent Module if the current path has one (there can be only one);
            let parentModule = this.parentModules.filter(module => {
              return module.path === route.data.moduleName;
            })[0];

            // Manage empty paths for lazy-loaded child routes
            if (currentParent == null) {
              currentParent = '';
            }

            // If there is a parentModule found AND the currentParent doesn't contain the module (for child cases)
            if (parentModule && currentParent != null && !currentParent.includes(parentModule.path)) {
              currentParent = String.prototype.concat(parentModule.parent, '/', parentModule.path);
            }
          }

          // Builds the path format if there is a parentNode
          if (currentParent != null) {
            pathFormatter = pathFormatter.concat(currentParent, '/', route.path);
          }

          this.navigableRoutes.push({
            path: pathFormatter ? pathFormatter : route.path,
            parent: currentParent,
            frenchName: route.data.frenchName,
            englishName: route.data.englishName,
            materialIcon: route.data.materialIcon,
            moduleName: route.data.moduleName ? route.data.moduleName : '',
            loadChildren: route.loadChildren ? route.loadChildren : '',
          });
        }
      }

      // Start a new nodeSearch on the child routes and sets the parentNode
      if (route.children && route.children.length > 0) {
        this.getRoutesToDisplay(route.children, pathFormatter ? pathFormatter : route.path);
      }
    });
  }
```

Things to notice :

- I use `displayRoute` from the route's data to select when I want my route to be displayed or not.
- I use `moduleName` from the route's data to link this route to the corresponding lazy-loaded module path name

Here is the output : [image]

**master.component.ts (2nd part)**

```
  navigationTree: RouteTreeDisplay[] = [];
  isFirstLevelDone = false;

  ...

  /**
  * Builds the NavigationTree from the navigable routes recursively built
  * @param {RouteDisplay[]} navigableRoutes Node of navigable routes routes to browse
  * @returns {RouteTreeDisplay[]} Tree of RouteTreeDisplay
  */
  buildNavigationTree(navigableRoutes: RouteDisplay[]): RouteTreeDisplay[] {
    let navigableRoutesCopy: RouteDisplay[] = Object.assign([], navigableRoutes);
    let navigationTree: RouteTreeDisplay[] = [];

    // Build treeRoots
    let navigationTreeRoots: RouteTreeDisplay[] = [];
    navigableRoutesCopy.forEach((route: RouteDisplay) => {
      // Set lazy-loaded module routes as TreeRoots
      let isLazyLoadedModuleRoute = navigationTree.filter((treeRoot: RouteTreeDisplay) => route.loadChildren && treeRoot.path === route.parent).length > 0;

      // Define TreeRoots
      if ((route.parent == null && !route.moduleName) || isLazyLoadedModuleRoute) {
        let treeRoot: RouteTreeDisplay = {
          path: route.path,
          children: [],
          englishName: route.englishName,
          frenchName: route.frenchName,
          materialIcon: route.materialIcon
        };
        navigationTree.push(treeRoot);
        navigationTreeRoots.push(treeRoot);
      }
    });

    // Clear treeRoots from the navigableRoutes
    navigableRoutesCopy = navigableRoutesCopy.filter(baseRoute => navigationTreeRoots.find(treeRoot => treeRoot.path === baseRoute.path) ? false : true);

    while (navigableRoutesCopy.length > 0) {
      navigableRoutesCopy = this.buildTreeChilds(navigationTree, navigableRoutesCopy);
    }

    // Delete empty treeRoots
    navigationTree = navigationTree.filter((treeRoots: RouteTreeDisplay) => treeRoots.children && treeRoots.children.length > 0);

    return navigationTree;
  }
```

**master.component.ts (3rd and last part)**

```
  /**
   * Builds treeChilds from the treeRoots
   * @param navigationTree The whole navigation Tree containing the treeRoots and their treeChilds
   * @param navigableRoutes The remaining navigableRoutes that are to be linked to their respectives treeRoots
   * @returns {RouteDisplay[]} The remaining navigableRoutes after some childs have been taken care of
   *
   * @todo : Might need to update the way the childs are filtered : // .filter(routes => !routes.loadChildren && routes.path.includes(child.path))
   * @see Doesn't manage duplicate sub route paths (yet) : see @todo
   */
  buildTreeChilds(navigationTree: RouteTreeDisplay[], navigableRoutes: RouteDisplay[]): RouteDisplay[] {
    // Build treeChilds
    navigationTree.forEach((treeRoot: RouteTreeDisplay) => {
      let treeChilds: RouteTreeDisplay[] = [];

      if (!this.isFirstLevelDone) {
        treeChilds =
          navigableRoutes
            .filter(routes => !routes.loadChildren && routes.parent === treeRoot.path)
            .map(element => {
              // Reduce the properties to display
              return {
                englishName: element.englishName,
                frenchName: element.frenchName,
                materialIcon: element.materialIcon,
                path: element.path
              } as RouteTreeDisplay;
            });

        if (treeChilds.length > 0) {
          treeRoot.children = treeRoot.children.concat(treeChilds);

          // Clear treeChilds from the navigableRoutes
          navigableRoutes = navigableRoutes.filter(baseRoute => treeChilds.find(treeChild => treeChild.path === baseRoute.path) ? false : true);
          treeChilds = [];
        }

      } else {
        // Improve this later on when needed
        treeRoot.children.forEach(child => {
          treeChilds = treeChilds.concat(
            navigableRoutes
              .filter(routes => !routes.loadChildren && routes.path.includes(child.path))
              .map(element => {
                // Reduce the properties to display
                return {
                  englishName: element.englishName,
                  frenchName: element.frenchName,
                  materialIcon: element.materialIcon,
                  path: element.path
                } as RouteTreeDisplay;
              })
          );

          if (treeChilds.length > 0) {
            treeRoot.children = treeRoot.children.concat(treeChilds);

            // Clear treeChilds from the navigableRoutes
            navigableRoutes = navigableRoutes.filter(baseRoute => treeChilds.find(treeChild => treeChild.path === baseRoute.path) ? false : true);
            treeChilds = [];
          }
        });
      }

    });
    this.isFirstLevelDone = true;
    return navigableRoutes;
  }
```

Here is the output : [image]

Comment: are you sure what you're asking is possible?  Logically, i don't see how you can add routing information to the main navigation from a lazily loaded module without loading the lazily loaded module (unless you move the routing information out of the lazily loaded module). I mean, by definition, at load time of the app, the lazily loaded module code is not available

Comment: I believe you are right, and there is no solution apart from adding data to the sub routes in that case, however I am more wondering about an easier solution to build my `navigationRoutes` and my `navigationTree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your routes in a separate ts module, and export the route configuration from that module. Then, in your feature routing module, you can import that route configuration and use it within your lazily loaded feature module configuration.

You just have to be careful what you put in that route configuration ts module - ensure that you don't reference any Types from your feature module to ensure that your module bundler doesn't end up including parts of your feature module in your main, eagerly loaded bundle.

As for consuming that route configuration to build your navigation - i didn't inspect your code in great detail - i think you have the right idea of looping through the routing configuration and including links as per the routing definition.